# How to using class name as generic parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

My code is like below

```
deserialize(myClass: MyClass) : MyClass {
    return Utils.deserialize(MyClass, myClass);
}
```

How can I write this code with generic parameter

```
deserialize<T extends IBaseModel>(myClass: T) : T
```

Comment: What exactly didn't work?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to pass in the class itself and not and instance: `deserialize<T extends IBaseModel>(myClass: new () => T) : T` and you can then call `deserialize(MyClass)`